# Processing names and meanings from .txt files

Tags: java

I wrote this program to process the names and meanings from .txt files. From the `while` loops I wrote, I noticed they are very similar loops containing `Scanner`s. I am wondering if there is any way to reduce the redundancy in the code.
Also, for this program my instructor only allows us to use Scanners, while and if/else loops, boolean and file input to solve this problem.

Here are samples for `names.txt` and `meanings.txt`:

`names.txt`

> Jax    M  0  0 0 0  0  0 0  0  0 0 0  0  347
>
> Randall   M 974 620  650 467  369  232  70 59 100 136 192  440  841
>
> Minnie  F  8 22 50 87 122  168  258  516  995  0 0  0  0
>
> Brianna F  0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0 340 61  15  30

`meanings.txt`

> MUBINA f Arabic Feminine form of MUBIN
>
> ANDRONIKOS m Ancient Greek Means "victory of a man" from Greek
>
> (andros) "of a man" and (nike) "victory".
>
> SALVATORE m Italian Italian cognate of SALVADOR

And here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class BabyNames {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
      Scanner inputName = new Scanner(new File("names.txt"));
      Scanner inputMeanings = new Scanner(new File("meanings.txt"));
      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
  
      intro();
      System.out.print("Name: ");
      String nameIn = console.next();
      System.out.print("Gender (M or F): ");  
      String genderIn = console.next();
  
      nameAndMeaning(inputName, inputMeanings, nameIn, genderIn);
   }
   
   public static void intro() {
      System.out.println("This program allows you to search through the");
      System.out.println("data from the Social Security Administration");
      System.out.println("to see how popular a particular name has been");
      System.out.println("since 1890.");
      System.out.println();
   }

   public static void nameAndMeaning(Scanner inputName, Scanner inputMeanings, String nameIn, String genderIn) {
      boolean hasLine = false;
      while(inputName.hasNextLine()) {
         String line = inputName.nextLine();
         Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);
         if(lineScan.hasNext()) {
            String name = lineScan.next();
            String gender = lineScan.next();
            if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(nameIn) && gender.equalsIgnoreCase(genderIn)) {
               hasLine = true;
               System.out.println(line);   
            } 
         }
      }
      if(hasLine == false) {
         System.out.println("\""+ nameIn + "\" not found.");
      } else {
         while(inputMeanings.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = inputMeanings.nextLine();
            Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);
            if(lineScan.hasNext()) {
               String name = lineScan.next();
               String gender = lineScan.next();
               if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(nameIn) && gender.equalsIgnoreCase(genderIn)) {
                  String meaning = line;
                  System.out.println(line);
               } 
            }           
         }   
      }
   }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate why searching `names.txt` is required? If I want to check the meaning, the `meanings.txt` file seems to contain all the data I need

Comment: If this is homework problem, you should probably add a [tag:homework] tag.

Answer (score 3):

I would start from the declaration of `main`. You are `throwing` an `exception` from it but no other class will handle it. You should put your `Scanners` inside a `try-catch` and handle the exception properly.

I would also recommend reading everything from the files at once and use that `collection` of data in your code logic. A `Scanner` locks the file until it's finished with it.

Furthermore, you don't have to call `System.out.println(...)` just for the sake printing a new line. Use the `\n` escape sequence for doing the same

```
System.out.println("This program allows you to search through the \ndata from the Social Security Administration \nto see how popular a particular name has been \nsince 1890.\n");
```

The rest is just a search function to find the `meaning` based on the `name` and `gender`. I recommend creating a name `Baby` class with `name` and `gender` attributes and use a `Hashtable<Baby, String>` to search for the meaning. The class can be as simple as

```
class Baby{
    private String name;
    public String Name(){
        return name;
    }

    private boolean gender;
    public boolean Gender(){
        return gender;
    }

    public Baby(String name, boolean gender){
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
    }
}
```

The time complexity of searching a value from a `Hashtable` is close to O(1) while a typical looping mechanism is O(n). The speed becomes `n` times slower as the size of the collection increases.

You also have a lot of duplicate code in the two `while` statements. To resolve that I'd recommend extracting out the `if-else` logic outside and calling a common function with a single loop. Something like

```
bool foundMatch = findMatch(...);
if(foundMatch) {
  findMatch(...) // with different params now
}
else {
  // print error message
}
```

**Solving with Constraints**

Given the constraints for the solution, I'd solve it as below

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner consoleInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Welcome message
    System.out.println("This program allows you to search through the \ndata from the Social Security Administration \nto see how popular a particular name has been \nsince 1890.\n");

    // Receive user input
    System.out.print("Name: ");
    String inputName = consoleInput.next();
    System.out.print("Gender: ");
    String inputGender = consoleInput.next();

    consoleInput.close(); // Closed as not needed anymore

    try (Scanner namesScanner = new Scanner(new File("names.txt"));
            Scanner meaningsScanner = new Scanner(new File("meanings.txt"))) {

        String foundMatch = findMatch(inputName, inputGender, namesScanner);
        if(!foundMatch.equals("")){
            System.out.println(foundMatch);
            System.out.println(findMatch(inputName, inputGender, meaningsScanner));
        } else{
            System.out.println("\""+ inputName + "\" not found.");
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
        System.out.println("File Not Found");
    }
}

private static String findMatch(String name, String gender, Scanner fileScanner){
    while(fileScanner.hasNextLine()){
        String currentLine = fileScanner.nextLine();

        // Split it to a String array and check the first two values
        String contents[] = currentLine.split(" ");
        if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(contents[0]) && gender.equalsIgnoreCase(contents[1])){
            return currentLine;
        }
    }
    // if no returns occured till the end of the file
    return "";
}
```

Please note that

- The `Scanners` should be closed once you're done using them. Using `Try-with-resources` statement is a better alernative (as recommended in the comments). You don't have to worry about the `Scanners` being closed. The `try` block functions like a `using` from **C#** and releases all resources after the block itself is finished. The defined resources must implement the `java.io.Closeable` interface for this functionality and the Java project must use **Java SE 7** or above.
- Both name matching operations can be handled by the same function. The significance of positive matches is handled by the calling function. This also enforces **Single Responsibility Principle (SRP)** and improves code maintainability
- Use `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` instead of `equals()` to avoid using `toLowerCase()` on all strings
- `return` is called immediately from the function on the first match to avoid redundant checks

Now if you'll be very strict and won't accept the use of a `String` array. You can replace it by extracting the first and second values using `substring(...)` function on the first two `whitespaces`

Comment: Hey, Paras. Thank you so much however in this assignment i am not allowed to use Hashtable. Would you mind explaining what is a try-catch? does it mean containing return statements? Thanks!

Comment: If you have constraints, please mention them in the question (are you not allowed to use any constraints? ). I'll update the answer accordingly. And yeah posting the code soon for more context

Comment: ok! got it! ill go edit the question!

Comment: it would also help if you can post a sample of the `names.txt` and `meanings.txt` files

Comment: @KaitlynHe I've updated the answer

Comment: "The `Scanners` should be closed once you're done using them." ... why not propose try-with-resources then?

Comment: @Vogel612 thanks for the tip, I've updated the answer accordingly.